# git rebase fatal: Needed a single revision invalid upstream –i

Tags: git

I am trying to squanshing several commits together. When I used

```
git rebase –i HEAD~8
```

I got a fatal:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream –i
```

Here is a part of commit logs:
[git log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wF8A.png)

All of the commits history of the corresponding Github repository is here:
https://github.com/yikouniao/YukiLog/commits/master

### Edit1:

When I used git `rebase –i HEAD~2`, I got the same result.

### Edit2:

I didn't know I had modified the file`.gitconfig`, `editor = notepad2` was add to the file. After I removed `editor = notepad2`, everything is OK. Then I rebased and squanshed 8 commits successfully.

Comment: What is the output when you try: `git rebase -i --root`?

Comment: Solved this issue by making sure upstream was set with `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`. Then I could `git rebase -i --root`

Comment: In my case, I added the upstream repo as a remote, but forgot to fetch from it. `git fetch upstream` downloaded the latest changes, then `git rebase upstream/develop` worked.

Comment: I got this issue resolved by adding "origin" to branch name: git rebase –i origin/HEAD~8. Don't forget to fetch first.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Several options:

- You are not on a branch (`Detached head`) or maybe you are trying to `rebase` or the wrong branch.
  Checkout the branch you want to `rebase` and try again.
- you don't have 8 commits in your history (you have 7 or less)
- try: `git rebase -i --root`

Here is the documentation for the `--root` flag and why it will work for you.

**`--root`**

```
Rebase all commits reachable from <branch>, instead of limiting them with
an <upstream>.This allows you to rebase the root commit(s) on a branch.  
When used with --onto, it will skip changes already contained in `<newbase>`   
(instead of `<upstream>`) whereas without --onto it will operate on every 
change. When used together with both --onto and --preserve-merges, all root 
commits will be rewritten to have `<newbase>` as parent instead.`
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although I still don't know why it went wrong, the problem is solved.

Comment: What does `upstream` mean in `instead of limiting them with
an <upstream>`?

Comment: In my case, I was rebasing onto "master", but I had just renamed my master to something else (to remind myself that it had diverged from upstream). Oops!

Comment: Thank heavens for this. Talk about bad UX.

Comment: "you don't have 8 commits in your history (you have 7 or less)". I saw this and changed `... HEAD~3` to `... HEAD~2` in my three-commit practice repo, and it let me squash.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is the dash in your –i. It's an en-dash (U2013) instead of a hyphen (U002D). I confirmed this by copying your dash and looking it up at http://unicode.scarfboy.com. Change it to -i instead.

The clue was the error message "invalid upstream –i". Git didn't recognize your –i as a flag and was instead interpreting it as the upstream parameter.